# Lucene suggest service

Tags: lucene

We are trying to use Lucene suggest service (`AnalyzingSuggester`) for autocomplete and want to apply custom filters on the results. Seems that `AnalyzingSuggester` or `AnalyzingInfixSuggester` doesn't take filters to be applied.

Really appreciate on any inputs.

Comment: What do you mean?  You want to add a `TokenFilter` to the analysis?  You'dd need to incorporate that into the `Analyzer`.

Comment: As far as I know you don't have any filter mechanism for the suggesters. You should wrap the LookupResults in your own logic. You can give some example of what sort of filtering you want and we can find a workaround here.

Answer (score 1):

I will use Lombok for brevity:

```
@Getter
public class Item {
    private final String suggestibleText;
    private final String arbitraryData; // additional arbitrary data you want to store in the index
    /**
     * These are data you can use for additional filtering
     */
    private final Collection<String> contexts;
    /*
     * order suggestion results. Higher weight are returned first.
     */
    private final int weight;
}
```

////

```
import org.apache.lucene.search.suggest.InputIterator;
import org.apache.lucene.util.BytesRef;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;

class ItemIterator implements InputIterator {

    private final Iterator<Item> entityIterator;
    private Item currentItem;

    public ItemIterator(final Iterator<Item> entityIterator) {
        this.entityIterator = entityIterator;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasContexts() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasPayloads() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public BytesRef next() {
        if (entityIterator.hasNext()) {
            currentItem = entityIterator.next();
            try {
                return new BytesRef(currentItem.getSuggestibleText().getBytes("UTF8"));
            } catch (final UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                throw new Error("Couldn't convert to UTF-8");
            }
        } else { // returning null is fine for lucene...
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public BytesRef payload() { // returns null if no payload from Item
        try {
            return new BytesRef(currentItem.getArbitraryData().getBytes("UTF8"));
        } catch (final UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            throw new Error("Could not convert to UTF-8");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Set<BytesRef> contexts() { // returns null if no context from Item
        try {
            final Set<BytesRef> contexts = new HashSet<>();
            for (final String context : currentItem.getContexts()) {
                contexts.add(new BytesRef(context.getBytes("UTF8")));
            }
            return contexts;
        } catch (final UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            throw new Error("Couldn't convert to UTF-8");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public long weight() {
        return currentItem.getWeight();
    }
}
```

///

```
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.WhitespaceAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.search.suggest.Lookup;
import org.apache.lucene.search.suggest.analyzing.AnalyzingInfixSuggester;
import org.apache.lucene.store.RAMDirectory;
import org.apache.lucene.util.BytesRef;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;

import static java.util.Arrays.asList;

public class SuggesterDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final RAMDirectory indexDir = new RAMDirectory();
        final WhitespaceAnalyzer analyzer = new WhitespaceAnalyzer();

        final AnalyzingInfixSuggester suggester = new AnalyzingInfixSuggester(indexDir, analyzer, analyzer, 3, true);

        final List<Item> entities = new ArrayList<>();

        entities.add(new Item("abacus", "", asList("ctx1", "ctx2"), 3) );
        entities.add(new Item("abandonware", "", asList("ctx1"), 2));
        entities.add(new Item("abandon", "", asList("ctx1"), 4));
        entities.add(new Item("abash", "", asList("ctx1", "ctx2"), 1));

        suggester.build(new ItemIterator(entities.iterator()));

        // lookup

        List<Lookup.LookupResult> results;
        final HashSet<BytesRef> contexts = new HashSet<>();
        contexts.add(new BytesRef("ctx1".getBytes("UTF8")));
        results = suggester.lookup("ab", contexts, 10, true, true);

        for (final Lookup.LookupResult result : results) {
            System.out.println("weight:: " + result.value + " key:: " + result.key + " payload:: " + result.payload.utf8ToString());
        }
        suggester.close();
    }
}
```